# I don't know how to define my array after transforming it with SheetJS

Tags: javascript, json, excel, templates, literals

I am kind of new to js so my apologies for this question.

I wrote some code for a tool that shows news cards from an array of objects using **template literals:**

```js
document.getElementById("Newscards").innerHTML =`
 <p class="Newscardstitle">External News</p>

 ${Worksheet.reverse()
  .map(function(Atribute){
  return `
  <div class="newcard">
  <div class="containernewphoto">
  <img class= "newphoto" src="${Atribute.Image}"></img> </div>
  <div class="containernewtext"> <p class="newdate"> ${Atribute.Date}</p>
  <p class="newheadline"><a href="${Atribute.Link}">${Atribute.Headline}</a></p>
  
  <p class= "newdescription">${Atribute.Description}</p>
</div>
  </div>
  `
 }).join('')}

 `
```

Right now I am using a js file from a json that look like this:

```js
const Articles =
[
  {
    "Date": "2019-11-04",
    "Headline": "",
    "Description": "",
    "Link": "",
    "Icon": "Military",
    "Latitude": 36.174523,
    "Longitude": 36.637775,
    "Image": ".jpg",
    "Added": "06/11/2019"
  },
...
]
```

However, it is quite inconvinient because I have to change the XLSX, then convert it on online platforms to json and change manually the json js file. I thought that SheetJS could help me in converting the XLSX to JSON automatically, so I added this code:

```js
  /* set up XMLHttpRequest */
  var url = "SyriaNews.xlsx";
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("GET", url, true);
  oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

        oReq.onload = function(e) {
            var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

            /* convert data to binary string */
            var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
            var arr = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
            var bstr = arr.join("");

            /* Call XLSX */
            var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {
                type: "binary"
            });


            /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
            var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
            /* Get worksheet */
            var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
            console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
                raw: true
            }));
        }

        oReq.send();

 document.getElementById("Newscards").innerHTML =`
 <p class="Newscardstitle">External News</p>

 ${**Worksheet**.reverse()
  .map(function(Atribute){
  return `
  <div class="newcard">
  <div class="containernewphoto">
  <img class= "newphoto" src="${Atribute.Image}"></img> </div>
  <div class="containernewtext"> <p class="newdate"> ${Atribute.Date}</p>
  <p class="newheadline"><a href="${Atribute.Link}">${Atribute.Headline}</a></p>
  
  <p class= "newdescription">${Atribute.Description}</p>
</div>
  </div>
  `
 }).join('')}

 `
```

In the console I get the correct array of objects but I am not able to define the JSON object after the XLSX has been transformed so it can be called for the template literals. I don't know which part has to be changed.